# Derivatives of a simple function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

I have asked this seemingly very simple question here a while ago but did not get any answer. Consider the function $f(x)=x^b(1−x)^{1-b}$ defined on $[0,1]$, with $0<b<1$. How can we prove that the even derivatives $f^{(2k)}$ have a constant sign on $(0,1)$? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: Consider $\varphi(x)=ln(f(x))$.